# Gradle Docker Build Issues

Tags: java, docker, api, kotlin, gradle

I have a Dockerfile with the following contents:

```
FROM gradle:6.9.1-jdk17 as builder
COPY services/api/build.gradle.kts ./
COPY services/api/src ./
COPY services/api/settings.gradle.kts ./
RUN gradle build --no-daemon

FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim
COPY --from=builder /home/* /home
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "./home/build/libs/api.jar" ]
```

When I copy from builder using `COPY --from=builder /home/* /home` it works with no issue and if I `sh` into the image I can see that there is a folder structure inside the `home` folder including `build/libs/api.jar`. However I want to copy just the `JAR` file , so I want to run `COPY --from=builder /home/build/libs/api.jar .` which should allow me to simply call `ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "./api.jar" ]` instead of the fully qualified `ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "./home/build/libs/api.jar" ]`.

Secondly, when I try running the image the container says `Error: Could not find or load main class com.library.api.MainKt`. So I tried building the `api.jar` file locally using the `gradle build --no-daemon` command that I am running in my `dockerfile` and reducing the `dockerfile`'s contents to simply copy that file from the local build folder (omitting the gradle build altogether) and this runs it perfectly.

I'm tearing my hair out on this issue. My gut says it's gradle not building the jar in the same way in the dockerfile as it is on my machine, but the versions are the same and I am struggling to see what else could be different.

For reference, my `build.gradle.kts` contents are as follows:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.31"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.31"
}

group "com.cabanta"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  ...
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "15"
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.library.api.MainKt"
    }
    exclude("META-INF/*.RSA", "META-INF/*.SF", "META-INF/*.DSA")

    // To add all of the dependencies otherwise a "NoClassDefFoundError" error
    from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from({
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
    })
}
```

If you need anything else to be able to answer, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for any help you wonderful people can give.

a final piece of pertinent information may be that my main class doesn't have a class, it simply has a `main()` as a function (as should be allowed in Kotlin and like I said, it builds and works when running through gradle on the local machine)

Comment: Have you tried to binary compare jar files build inside docker and on your machine?

Comment: i hadn't, but have since learnt to cp out the jar file and inspect it. It turns out that the com folder was empty, so the initial copy was the actual issue. 

I have not changed this to copy the entire `src` folder and then build from there. This then gives the correct `.jar` file and I can copy that on it's own rather than copy the whole build folder.

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be the way that I was copying files from local to the gradle step.

```
COPY services/api/build.gradle.kts ./
COPY services/api/src ./
COPY services/api/settings.gradle.kts ./
```

This, I have now changed to `COPY services/api/* ./`, which copies all of the build files that are needed.

The API before, was being created, however it was being created without any content, which meant that Java couldn't find the class ... because it was never there in the first place.